# pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException error when filtering the df

Tags: pyspark

I want to select all rows from a pyspark df except some rows where the array contains 1. It works with the code below in the notebook:

`<pyspark df>.filter(~exists("<col name>", lambda x: x=="hello"))`

But when I write it as this:

```
cond = '~exists("<col name>", lambda x: x=="hello")'
df = df.filter(con)
```

I got error as below:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: 
extraneous input 'x' expecting {')', ','}(line 1, pos 32)
```

I really can't spot any typo. Could someone give me a hint if I missed something?

Thanks, J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass in the conditions through variable, it needs to be written in the form of
`expr str` of spark sql. So it can be modified to:

```
cond = '!exists(col_name, x -> x == "hello")'
```

Comment: This should work, thanks! But does this change the col type to string from array? It's weird that I got an error saying the column is of string so there's a data type mismatch...

Comment: No,it doesn't change the column type!